# prestashop theme CSS blinking buttons

Tags: prestashop

Hi I have problem with css on my page and i am totally stuck.

[On this page](http://www.luxury-fashion.sk)

In the middle of page is slider with products and if mouse is on the price there is unwanted effect price disappear somewhere.

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove this css rule:

Lines `195 - 201` @ file `/modules/itemslider/css/itemslider.css`:

```
#itemslider li:hover .price span {

  opacity:0;

  filter:alpha(opacity=0);  

}
```

Property `Opacity = 0` mean that the item is totaly see-thought (0% visible)

The recommended way is to copy this file to

`themes/yuortheme/css/modules/itemslider/css/itemslider.css`

and make your changes to this file (your own, customized file). When you update the module this file will still be here.